# Rearranging nominal factors on boxplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating boxplots with the factor beings seasons, but it automatically rearranges the seasons in alphabetical order (e.g autumn, spring, summer, winter) instead of in the order the seasons should follow. I would like to rearrange them so they follow the order; spring, summer, autumn, winter.

I have tried using forcats and the code 
     pre$season <- factor(pre$season, levels = c("spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter"))
 but neither have worked with any sucess.

This is the basic code for the boxplots I have used:

```
ggplot(pre, aes(x=season, y=anomaly)) + 
 geom_boxplot(color="skyblue1", fill="skyblue1", alpha=0.4) +
  geom_jitter(width=0.1,alpha=0.5, colour="limegreen") +
  ylim(-3,9) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  labs(title = " ") +
  theme_classic() +
  coord_flip()
```

The dataset is as followed:

anomaly season  sf
-1.511  winter  1.012
-1.784  winter  0.739
0.499   spring  3.022
4.476   spring  6.999
3.976   spring  6.499
-0.732  summer  1.791
-0.656  summer  1.867
-1.131  summer  1.392
-2.335  autumn  0.188
-1.692  autumn  0.831
0.573   autumn  3.096
-0.380  winter  2.143

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just to add in more move version using forcats

```
pre <- pre %>%
  mutate(season = fct_relevel(season, "autumn", "winter", "summer", 
"spring"  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)


seasons %>%
    mutate(season = ordered(season, levels = c("spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter"))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = season, y=anomaly)) + 
    geom_boxplot(color="skyblue1", fill="skyblue1", alpha=0.4) +
    geom_jitter(width=0.1,alpha=0.5, colour="limegreen") +
    ylim(-3,9) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("") +
    labs(title = " ") +
    theme_classic() +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a base R alternative:

```
pre$season <- ordered(pre$season, levels = c("spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter"))
```

Note also that your original attempt `pre$season <- factor(pre$season, levels = c("spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter"))` would work had you added `order = TRUE`, i.e.:

```
pre$season <- factor(pre$season, levels = c("spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter"), order = TRUE)
```